# Using RPC's for movement of an object across a network

Tags: c#, unity, networking, movement

I've been building upon http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/DarrelCusey/20130221/187128/Unity_Networking_Sample_Using_One_NetworkView.php At the moment when I spawn a sphere on the server it spawns on the clients aswell. On the server side I have two buttons, move left and move right. Ive been trying to get the movement to go across to the clients aswell but to no avail. The sphere moves on the server but nothing on the clients. Below is the code I have attempted, where have I went wrong with this? The debug line in SendSpherePosition outputs the spheres position perfect, but the position is not updating on the client, so is it a problem with the line below it "spawnedSphere.transform.position = spherePosition;"?

```
 if (Network.isServer && isSphereSpawned==true && closeOutExtras==false) 
     {
         Debug.Log("the position of the sphere is: " + spawnedSphere.transform.position );    
         //If called here sphere's continuously spawn on the client
         networkView.RPC("TellClientsToSpawnSphere", RPCMode.Others, null);
         //put this bool in just to have one spawn on the client, bad code, will need to change
         closeOutExtras = true;
     }

     if (Network.isServer && isSphereSpawned==true) 
     {
         Debug.Log("the position of the sphere is: " + spawnedSphere.transform.position );    
         if (lastLocalSpherePosition != spawnedSphere.transform.position)
         {
             networkView.RPC("SendSpherePosition", RPCMode.Others, spawnedSphere.transform.position);
             lastLocalPlayerPosition = spawnedSphere.transform.position;
         }
     }

 }

 [RPC]
 void SendSpherePosition(Vector3 spherePosition)
 {
     Debug.Log ("The sphere position is: " + spherePosition);         
     spawnedSphere.transform.position = spherePosition;
 }

 [RPC]
 void TellClientsToSpawnSphere()
 {
     Instantiate (spawnedSphere);
 }
```

Comment: Did you just re post an old question again? : http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/86544/spawning-a-sphere-and-trying-to-move-it

Comment: Ahh no I didnt, that was for movement on the server side, just locally, this is for across the network. So when it moves on the server it also moves on the client.

Comment: Please take a look at the [help]; a lot of the questions you've asked are of the "debug my code" variety which are often difficult to answer without discussion and almost always entirely useless for future users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather from your code spawnedSphere is NOT the game object that has been spawned, but the prefab. Do this:

```
GameObject sphere;

[RPC]
void SendSpherePosition( Vector3 spherePosition )
{
    sphere.transform.position = spherePosition;
}

[RPC]
void TellClientsToSpawnSphere()
{
    sphere = Instantiate( spawnedSphere ) as GameObject;
}
```

Catch the returned GameObject of Instantiate, and that is your sphere. Move that instead.

Comment: I have above all this "public GameObject spawnedSphere;" so when I try what you suggested it just goes all red on me :( And also the TellClientsToSpawnSphere seems to work fine as it is

Comment: Yeah, spawnedSphere is the prefab in this case. You instantiate a prefab, and then a GameObject is returned. That game object is your sphere. spawnedSphere is like a template.

Comment: @CH99 You don't seem to understand Instantiate. Go read about it for 5 minutes and you'll easily see what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Taking a quick read I understand were I went wrong now! Instantiate and RPC's etc are all still new to me, thanks for the comments and answer! :)